# Who is trying to categorize my website?

Tags: logging

Caught this in the logs the other day:

```
Started GET "/verify-UncategorisedWebsite?aHR0cHM6Ly93d3=" for 198.240.130.75 at 2012-12-03 14:51:50 +0000
```

I bumped around a bit and couldn't find anything that should be searching for that.  Is this a webcrawler?  If so, anyone know who?

Comment: It gives you the ip address.  How are we suppose to know who owns it?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from doing the usual reverse dns and a whois lookups, you're left with the option to phone [these people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_Suisse) and ask them what they want from you.

```
$ dig -x 198.240.130.75  |grep ';; ANSWER' -A1
;; ANSWER SECTION:
75.130.240.198.in-addr.arpa. 86164 IN   PTR     ny-bas00.csfb.com.
```

```
$ bwwhois csfb.com | grep Registrant -A 111
Registrant:
  Credit Suisse Group (CREDITSU6216)
  Uetlibergstrasse 231
  Zurich, ZH, 8070
  CH
  Domain name: csfb.com
```

Technical contact:
  Tech, CANA (CC4047)
  Credit Suisse Group
  CANA Services
  Uetlibergstrasse 231
  Zurich, ZH, 8070
  CH
  list.canatech@credit-suisse.com
  +41.443322602 Fax: +41.444666333

Administrative contact:
  Administrator, CANA (CA3213)
  Credit Suisse Group
  CANA Services
  Uetlibergstrasse 231
  Zurich, ZH, 8070
  CH
  admin.cana@credit-suisse.com
  +41.443322602 Fax: +41.444666333

```
Record created:           2006-12-20 17:01:04
Record last updated:      2012-10-22 00:22:26
Record expires:           2013-10-20 00:00:00
```

Domain servers in listed order:
  dns1.credit-suisse.com (DNSCREDI836)
  dns2.credit-suisse.com (DNSCREDI367)
  dns3.credit-suisse.com (DNSCREDI743)
  dns4.credit-suisse.com (DNSCREDI509)